# Pack symbols for files/folders in Nautilus more tightly

Tags: nautilus, customization

I don't like that Nautilus wastes so much screen space by keeping its symbols for files/folders far apart.

This screenshot and the modification of it I quickly made with Gimp shows that you can save a lot of space if decrease the amount of space between the items:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

The answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135998/how-to-reduce-the-spacing-between-icons-in-nautilus) (which is about Ubuntu 12.04 but I use Ubuntu 16.04 and furthermore only talks about horizontal spacing which arguably is more important to reduce than horizontal spacing because the waste of vertical space isn't as extreme) didn't help.

Comment: I'm not posting it as an answer, because it doesn't answer your question... but do you realize that you can zoom in and out to change the thumbnail size? `Ctrl +/-`, `Ctrl` + scrollwheel or through the menu (`View->Zoom In/Out`). It _would_ be nice to reduce the padding between thumbnails though. Good question!

Comment: @Lambart I tried this as a workaround but it makes the thumbnails of pictures too small. I can't see them properly any more when setting it too small. For those for whom that's not a problem: Change the default zoom level of Nautilus via donf because it doesn't get saved automatically when you just press `Ctrl + -`. It's `org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view.default-zoom-level`.

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552093 -- it's allegedly resolved, though I'm not sure the resolution is going to make us happy once it makes its way to Ubuntu...

Comment: also related: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745968

Comment: In any case, if you haven't read the news this week... Unity is going away, GNOME is coming back to Ubuntu. I wonder if Nautilus (a GNOME application, after all) will work better when it's not being patched to work with Unity.

Comment: @Lambart I have and I tried out several distros the last few days, looking for the desktops they use and their modifications of them and reporting bugs so they might be fixed when I move away from Ubuntu should I not like what comes after 16.04. I haven't found anything I like. Looks like I'll stick with Ubuntu. There will be support for 16.04 until 2021. Still 4 years to go. 4 years in which having more tightly packed icons in Nautilus would be a good thing.